# OOP COM Server Updates clients

Tags: c++, com, atl

I have an out of process ATL COM server (exe).  When it is started by a Client the server spawns a worker thread which polls for some data.  Every time the data is updated I want to notify all of the clients with the updated value.

I have created a COM Client, which connects via CoCreateInstanceEx, creates its Sink object, gets the connection point and calls Advise, all without error.  However, When the server tries to Fire_event, it's IConnectionPointImpl::m_vec is empty and no clients are ever notified.

I assume this is because the server creates its own object, so I end up with two instances of IConnectionPointImpl::m_vec, one from the server and one from the client when it calls Advise.  How can I get the server data to the clients?

Comment: I guess you have to find out why the events are being fired on the object different from one created for the client and why there's more than one object in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend this approach. Create a plain vanilla C++ singleton (not a COM object) - let's call it `S`. `S` would hold a list of weak, non-`AddRef`'ed references to all outstanding COM objects (a C++ class pointer, rather than a COM interface pointer, would be convenient). Your COM objects would register themselves with `S` in their constructor, and deregister in destructor.

When something interesting happens, your worker thread would notify (call a method on) `S`, which would notify all registered COM objects, which would call `Fire_event` on themselves.

Be careful when firing events from a worker thread. This is illegal, unless both your main thread and worker thread enter MTA. See http://vcfaq.mvps.org/com/1.htm for details and some workarounds.